# Question about simulation relations

Tags: automata

I was perusing the internet for a precise def. of a simulation relation and one of the top search results was a paper *Bisimulation, The Supervisory Control Problem and Strong Model Matching for Finite State Machines*, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Example-of-simulation-relation_fig2_262243963. The authors say that F2 simulates F1, but F1 does not simulate F2. I understand intuitively why this is the case (F1 can't make a transition on 'b' if it were to end up in state C). However I don't see how it follows from their defn, for example the following seems like a simulation relation : {(1,A), (2,B), (2,C), (3,D), (4,E)}. If this is indeed a simulation relation, and as its total on F2 and 1 and A are the respective start states of the two automata, then should it not be the case that F1 simulates F2?

Their def. of simulation (Def 2.9) is
Let H and G be [labeled transition systems]. A simulation relation of H and G wrt $\Sigma_S \subseteq \Sigma_H$ is a binary relation $S \subseteq X_H \times X_G$ satisfying

1. If $x_HSx_G$ and $\sigma \in \Sigma_S$ and $x_H \longrightarrow_\sigma x'_H$ then there exists $x'_G$ s.t. $x_G \longrightarrow_\sigma x'_G$ and $x'_HSx'_G$
2. (Simulation with marking) $x_HSx_G$  implies $x_H \in X_{Hm}$ iff $x_G \in X_{Gm}$

$X_H,X_G$ are the node alphabets resp. and $X_{Hm},X_{Gm}$ are subsets of $X_H,X_G$ that represent marked states

Comment: What is the definition of simulation relation that you are using?

Comment: I've updated the question with the def of a simulation relation from the paper

Comment: I realized my mistake - the \sigma on the transition is an arc label. Whether Node 1 in F2 is mapped to Node B or C (or both) in F1, while Node1 can transition on either "b" or "c", B cannot make a transition on "c", and C cannot make a transition on "b". So that is why F1 doesn't simulate F2.